# Print lines that already have newlines from the old file into a new file in the same line

Tags: python

I want the `newline` to be printed only once between 3 sentences. But by this following `code`, each sentence was printed with `newline` and one extra `newline` before new `index` sentence.

```
with open(convert_file) as infile:
for line in infile:
    with open('convert-profile.txt', "a") as f1:
        if "index" in line:
            f1.write("\n"+line)
        elif "scan start time" in line:
            f1.write(line)  
        elif "binary: [4]" in line:
            f1.write(line)
        f1.close
```

I guess because each `index`, `scan time`, and `binary` in the old file `convert_file` ends with a `newline`. 
How to append these three in the same `line` and write them in a new file?

---

Another thing here, when I use `"w"` mode for `print`, it seems to keep printing on the first line. At the end, I got a blank file. What mode I should use if I want it to re-write on the file every time I run the `code` when `"w"` does not work?

Comment: `f1.close` does nothing. Fortunately context manager closes the file... if you open the same file in a loop with `w` mode, that's expected that you only get the result of the last iteration... It's not clear. Can you show us what you expect and what you get?

Comment: About `w`, here it was wrong because I put `with open...` after for-loop. I fixed it by changing the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you build a `string` first for the line you want to write, then write the whole line. And if you want to remove the newline `character` you should use `line.rstrip()` as the following:

```
    line = line.rstrip()
    result = ''
    if "index" in line:
        result += line
    elif "scan start time" in line:
        result += line
    elif "binary: [4]" in line:
        result += line
    result += '\n'
```

And for the mode, `with open('convert-profile.txt', 'w') as f1:` should work just fine.